# How do i mock Url object in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, moq

A few of my controller actions call this method `GenerateActionLink`.

```
    private string GenerateActionLink(string actionName, string token, string username)
    {
        string validationLink = null;
        if (Request.Url != null)
        {
            var encodedToken = EncodedUrlParameter(token);
            var url = Url.Action(actionName, "Register", new {Token = encodedToken, Username = username}, Request.Url.Scheme);
            validationLink = url;
        }

        return validationLink;
    }
```

This is to generate a validation link which will be sent via email. It works perfectly. The issue I'm having is when testing a controller action which called the method. Url is null.

**How can i mock that and use the mock in my unit test ?**

I am using `Moq` and `NUnit`.

NOTE: I need to be able to pass in an actionName, this is why i am not concatinating Request.Url with my parameter values because Request.Url will always have the action the request comes from which is generally not the action i want in the link, this is why i am using Url.Action to generate an action link.

Comment: Mock `UrlHelper` and set the controller's `Url` property when arranging the test. To mock the request mock the controller's http context and set the controller context.

Answer (score 1):

Mock `UrlHelper` and set the controller's `Url` property when arranging the test. To mock the request mock the controller's http context and set the controller context.

To demonstrate here is a sample controller based on the provided example above.

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction() {
        var link = GenerateActionLink("MyTargetActionName", string.Empty, string.Empty);

        return View((object)link);
    }

    private string GenerateActionLink(string actionName, string token, string username) {
        string validationLink = null;
        if (Request.Url != null) {
            var encodedToken = EncodedUrlParameter(token);
            var url = Url.Action(actionName, "Register", new { Token = encodedToken, Username = username }, Request.Url.Scheme);
            validationLink = url;
        }

        return validationLink;
    }

    private string EncodedUrlParameter(string token) {
        return "Fake encoding";
    }

}
```

Here is a unit test example that mocks up all the necessary framework dependencies

```
[TestClass]
public class UrlHelperTest {
    [TestMethod]
    public void MockUrlHelper() {
        //Arrange
        var requestUrl = new Uri("http://myrequesturl");
        var request = Mock.Of<HttpRequestBase>();
        var requestMock = Mock.Get(request);
        requestMock.Setup(m => m.Url).Returns(requestUrl);

        var httpcontext = Mock.Of<HttpContextBase>();
        var httpcontextSetup = Mock.Get(httpcontext);
        httpcontextSetup.Setup(m => m.Request).Returns(request);


        var actionName = "MyTargetActionName";
        var expectedUrl = "http://myfakeactionurl.com";
        var mockUrlHelper = new Mock<UrlHelper>();
        mockUrlHelper
            .Setup(m => m.Action(actionName, "Register", It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(expectedUrl)
            .Verifiable();

        var sut = new MyController();
        sut.Url = mockUrlHelper.Object;
        sut.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext {
            Controller = sut,
            HttpContext = httpcontext,
        };

        //Act
        var result = sut.MyAction();

        //Assert
        mockUrlHelper.Verify();
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So this is my current solution, I ended up constructing the link manually. If there are any better solution please do let me know.

```
    private string GenerateActionLink(string actionName, string token, string username)
    {
        string validationLink = null;
        if (Request.Url != null)
        {
            var encodedToken = EncodedUrlParameter(token);
            var encodedEmail = EncodedUrlParameter(username);
            var concatenatedUrl =
                $"{Request.Url.Scheme}://{Request.Url.Host}/Register/{actionName}?Token={encodedToken}&Username={encodedEmail}"; 
            validationLink = concatenatedUrl;
        }

        return validationLink;
    }
```

This way i can still pass in an `actionName`. If I use the Request.Url, this will always have an action which is usually not what i want to use as stated in my question.